# How do I make my percentages have 2 decimal points?

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I have looked at other posts about this but i just can't get my head around it and wanted to ask specifically for my scenario. I have written a Visual Basic console application and I am trying to get my percentages to have two decimal places on them as they're just rounding up to the nearest whole number. Here is the code :

```
Console.Write("Enter the percentage you want to work out: ")
Dim Percentage As Integer
Percentage = Console.ReadLine()

Console.Write("What would you like to work out " & Percentage & "% of? ")
Dim Number As Integer
Number = Console.ReadLine()

Dim PercentageNumberResult As Integer
PercentageNumberResult = Number / 100 * Percentage

Console.Write(Number & " ÷ 100 × " & Percentage & " = " & PercentageNumberResult)
Console.ReadLine()
```

Any help would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: @AndrewMorton, you're thinking of C#.  In VB, the `/` operator produces a `Double` when both operands are type `Integer`.  You would need to use the `\\` operator for integer division.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Thanks :)

Comment: Are you aware that `Integer` means whole number?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is due to PercentageNumberResult being an integer.

Make PercentageNumberResult a double :

```
    Dim PercentageNumberResult As Double
    PercentageNumberResult = Number / 100 * Percentage
```

You could then use Math.Round if needed.  Also you should turn on Option Strict this will help solving the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to convert a number to a `String` then you call `ToString` on that number.  If you want a specific format then you pass the appropriate format specifier as an argument when calling `ToString`. You should read the relevant documentation to learn all the possible format specifiers.

In this case, you display a number as a percentage using the "p" or "P" specifier and you can add a number to specify the number of decimal places. e.g.

```
Dim x = 13
Dim y = 1000
Dim z = x / y
Dim s = z.ToString("P2")
```

After executing that code, `s` will contain "1.30%".

If you don't actually want the "%" symbol in the output then you can multiply by 100 and use a different format specifier, e.g.

```
Dim x = 13
Dim y = 1000
Dim z = 100 * x / y
Dim s = z.ToString("N2")
```

After executing that code, `s` will contain "1.30".